# testing ASP.NET MVC controller Httpget

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, testing

We just started using ASP.NET MVC3 and we want to unit test our controller.

Here is my controller function:

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult Action()
{
  Guid Id = Guid.Empty;
            string[] UrlSegments = Request.Url.Segments;
            Guid.TryParse(UrlSegments[UrlSegments.Count() - 1], out Id);
            if(Id == Guid.Empty)
                return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage");
  }
```

I want to test this controller function.I have put the matching route to match this function in my global.asax file. Basically I am trying to retrieve the guid from the URl and if it is not good then take him to error page.
HttpRequestBase class URl is no setter,so I am confused how to test this functionality?

Comment: I changed "if(Id == Guid.Empty)" to "if(activationId == Guid.Empty)", which hopefully is what was meant to be compared.

Comment: Thanks...I cleaned the id thing

Comment: what is not working and how? I would replace UrlSegments.Count() with UrlSegments.Length anyway...

Comment: I want to test this function using mock. How can I do that? I don't know how to create request object with the URl like "http://localhost/action/guid"

Comment: curious why are you checking url segments and not just letting binding work for you to populate it (or a custom binder)?

Comment: I was checking..if Guid is valid or not. What if the URL is manually forged or changed by changing the guid with 1234 or $#@%.

Comment: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-mvc-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

As for testing read the link provided in the [comments above](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-mvc-controllers/) but I would recommend doing some reading on [MVC Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) or [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx), it does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Have a look in your global.ascx.cs file you will find something like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This is the out of the box route for the MVC framework.

Routes will match a url based on the convention you give them.

So based on the default route above and given a url like this:

```
http://localhost:portnumber/MyController/MyAction/8B4B93DE-76CA-4552-B4AA-460400761EAD
```

It will try and match this url to a controller called MyController with an action called MyAction, which receives and Id. It will only hit this action if all the criteria match.

If there is no id in the URL and id defined on your action method is not a nullable type then it simple wont execute. It will rather try match another Url, if it cant find one it will give a 404.

Like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    Public ActionResult MyAction(Guid id)
    {

    }  
}
```